# Firestore Rules : Property is undefined on object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my local environement using the firebase emulator, I have the following rule that raises a `FirebaseError: Property managers is undefined on object. for 'list'`:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /businesses/{business} {
            allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.managers;
        }
    }
}
```

If I test the same rule on the rules Playground, it works correctly (`Simulated read allowed`)..

To prove I have the managers property defined and available, if I change the rule to `if true`, I can loop on the list with the following local data:

```js
// code
...
.then((snap) => snap.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())))

// output
VzaU8rX8HOgejk0fyOFK  =>  {..., managers: Array(1)}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you !

**UPDATE**

This is the code I would like to have the rule applied on:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("businesses")
            .where("slug", "==", params.slug)
            .get()
            .then((snap) => {
                if (!snap.empty) {
                    // slug is supposed to be unique, so I retrieve the first and only element
                    const doc = snap.docs[0]
                    setBusiness({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })
                    setState({ ...state, loading: false, data: true })
                } else {
                    setState({ ...state, loading: false, error: "Business not found" })
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error)
                setState({ ...state, loading: false, error: "Error getting document" })
            })
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rule works in the console simulator because it's only testing the read of a single docyment at a time.  Your client code, however, is performing a query for multiple documents, which is different.  One very important thing to know is that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) (be sure to read that, and [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003)).  Security rules will not remove documents from the result set if the rule would reject a document.  Instead, the query must be able to fetch all document allowed by the rule, or the rule will reject the query entirely.

**A query must explicitly have the same filter as required by the rules.**  Your rule requires that the query only filter for documents where the current user is in the managers array field.  Therefore, it the query must be more like this:

```
db.collection("businesses")
    .where("slug", "==", params.slug)
    .where("managers", "array-contains", uid)
```

Where `uid` is the current user's uid.

Comment: It would've been nice if the error message made this more clear. Usually Firestore permission errors result in a pretty good "permission denied" type of error message, but in this particular case (in the emulator only, I think) it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Could you try `db.collection("businesses").get("VzaU8rX8HOgejk0fyOFK");`?

Secondly, Did you use `array-contains`, `in`, or `array-contains-any` as `where()` method comparison operation?

If you not, Coud you try the following code?

ex.

```
db.collection("businesses").where("managers", "in", uid)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: Hello @zkohi, I have no problem to retrieve the data itself, but rather to restrict the access using the security rules. Are you sure your recommendation would help me?